# MYSQL - Import HTML files into a single column

Tags: mysql, load

I have around 1000 html files in my local computer and I have to import them into database table in a single column . I mean one full file into one cell and 1000 HTML files into 1000 rows .

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

one row contains ID and one html file contents

I tried

```
load DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\userD\\Desktop\\data\\alter-data.html' INTO TABLE content LINES TERMINATED BY '</html>';
```

since each file end line is `</html>` but that didn't help to load any data ..

Can any one help me on this?

Thank You

Regards

Kiran

Comment: You'll have to write a very small program in the language of your choice. Which one is it ?

Comment: why two '\\' in al the C: path?

Comment: Oh! OK , I will then write in PHP and do it through file upload ( Or I will try standard Java program )  Thanks for the hint . Thought there could be a simple way ...

Comment: jcho360 :- Thanks and It is windows , so I should give two slashes

Comment: Did you get any errors when you tried this? Or, no errors but just resulted in an empty table?

Comment: Thanks Girish rao , just empty table , I just found a Java program on the net and I am able to upload the contents without any issue .

Comment: Thanks again @dystroy . Your tip helped me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do  the same thing and spent ages working it out but it turned out to be simple.

Note the test table, test_html field was defined as a "text" field

```
truncate table test;
load data local infile 'data.htm' 
into table test
fields terminated by '</html>'
lines terminated by '</html>'
(test_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below Java program and able to upload the contents

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/core/files/javafilesavetodatabase.html

Thanks All

Regards

Kiran

Comment: @dystroy :- I have to wait till tomorrow to accept it . Thank You